# Time difference is not showing properly

Tags: php, datetime

Here is my code : current time - 14.32

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2015-10-12 14:34:00');
$datetime2 = new DateTime();
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->i.' minutes<br>';
```

The output : 35 Minutes

Why is the minutes is showing 35 instead of 2 minutes?

Comment: Well, it works if you use `$datetime2 = new DateTime('2015-10-12 14:32:00');`. Probably $datetime2 didn't return 14:32 as you expected.

Answer (score 1):

set the time zone,

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata"); 
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2015-10-12 14:34:00');
$datetime2 = new DateTime();
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->i.' minutes<br>';// for current time, difference is 10 minutes.
```